# Markov chain data processing inequality

Tags: markov-process, information-theory, mutual-information

For a Markov chain $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, we have the following data processing inequality: $I(Y;X) \ge I(Z;X)$. Now for the Markov chain, $(W,X) \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$, can we prove that the following inequality holds true: $I(Y; W,X) \ge I(Z; W,X)$? Also can we prove the followup inequality: $I(Z; Y) \ge I(Z; W,X)$? It intuitively makes sense, but is there any formal proof?

Comment: Set $T = (W, X)$.